# refresh JS Script without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, refresh

I'm using a free weather forecast widget in my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tools.tititudorancea.com/weather_forecast.js?place=zurich_2&amp;s=1&amp;days=5&amp;utf8=no&amp;columns=5&amp;temp=c"></script>
<div style="font: 10px Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000" align="right">
<a href="http://www.tititudorancea.com/z/weather.htm">Weather forecast</a> provided by <a href="http://www.tititudorancea.com/">tititudorancea.com</a></div>
```

My webpage will never reload itself and then the weather will never be updated. 
Is there a way to refresh the javascript without refreshing the all page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

```
var weatherURLSite = "http://tools.tititudorancea.com/weather_forecast.js?place=$placeID$&s=1&days=5&utf8=no&columns=5&temp=c";    
var specificWeather = weatherURLSite.replace("$placeID$", value);   
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: weatherURL,
            data: { url: specificWeather }
        }).done(
            function (content) {
                var li = "<li id='" + value + "'>" + content + creditsDiv + "</li>";
                $("#weather").append(li);                   
            });
```

And I added a timer to do the refresh periodically

```
var weatherTimer = self.setInterval(function () { GetReloadWeather('@Url.Action("GetWeather","Weather")'); }, 3600000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a bogus query var at the end of the url to force a refresh. Add an id to your script tag first then try this:

```
var weather = document.getElementById('weather');

weather.src += '&bogus='+ new Date(); // init

setInterval(function() {
  weather.src = weather.src.replace(/&.+$/, '&bogus='+ new Date());
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but sadly it didn't work, the weather is not updating it self. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I ended up with jQuery 'replaceWith' function

```
jQuery("script").eq(2).replaceWith('<script type="text/javascript" src="/state.js"></script>');
```